# kube-scheduler - error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Installing Kuberenetes on a Raspberry Pi 4 Cluster with 1 controller and 3 nodes running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Troubleshooting why the kube-scheduler keeps on failing.  There's a few issues but focusing on the scheduler first.

peter@k8s-controller:~/.kube$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS          AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-tsvqz                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (62s ago)       14m
kube-system    etcd-k8s-controller                      1/1     Running            599 (11m ago)     21h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-k8s-controller            1/1     Running            593 (3m3s ago)    21h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-k8s-controller   1/1     Running            202 (3m1s ago)    20h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-k8s-controller            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   646 (3m23s ago)   21h
```

peter@k8s-controller:~/.kube$ kubectl logs kube-scheduler-k8s-controller  -n kube-system

```
I1110 13:25:28.704409       1 serving.go:348] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
I1110 13:25:32.413200       1 server.go:148] "Starting Kubernetes Scheduler" version="v1.25.3"
I1110 13:25:32.413287       1 server.go:150] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
I1110 13:25:32.423337       1 secure_serving.go:210] Serving securely on 127.0.0.1:10259
I1110 13:25:32.423630       1 requestheader_controller.go:169] Starting RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I1110 13:25:32.423696       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I1110 13:25:32.423764       1 tlsconfig.go:240] "Starting DynamicServingCertificateController"
I1110 13:25:32.435757       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:202] "Starting controller" name="client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file"
I1110 13:25:32.435848       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I1110 13:25:32.436013       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:202] "Starting controller" name="client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
I1110 13:25:32.436061       1 shared_informer.go:255] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
I1110 13:25:32.524034       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I1110 13:25:32.524219       1 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/kube-scheduler...
I1110 13:25:32.536752       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
I1110 13:25:32.536766       1 shared_informer.go:262] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I1110 13:25:47.845015       1 leaderelection.go:258] successfully acquired lease kube-system/kube-scheduler
E1110 13:25:53.900211       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: Get "https://192.168.1.135:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-scheduler?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.1.135:6443: connect: connection refused
E1110 13:25:55.903003       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: Get "https://192.168.1.135:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-scheduler?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.1.135:6443: connect: connection refused
E1110 13:25:57.903128       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: Get "https://192.168.1.135:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-scheduler?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.1.135:6443: connect: connection refused
E1110 13:25:59.903225       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: Get "https://192.168.1.135:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-scheduler?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.1.135:6443: connect: connection refused
E1110 13:26:01.902986       1 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock kube-system/kube-scheduler: Get "https://192.168.1.135:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-system/leases/kube-scheduler?timeout=5s": dial tcp 192.168.1.135:6443: connect: connection refused
I1110 13:26:03.897984       1 leaderelection.go:283] failed to renew lease kube-system/kube-scheduler: timed out waiting for the condition
E1110 13:26:03.898239       1 leaderelection.go:306] Failed to release lock: resource name may not be empty
E1110 13:26:03.898323       1 server.go:220] "Leaderelection lost"
E1110 13:26:03.898587       1 scheduling_queue.go:963] "Error while retrieving next pod from scheduling queue" err="scheduling queue is closed"
```